# Python logging from multiple modules to same log file

Tags: python, logging

I am working on a Python library with multiple packages and a main routine outside these packages. I have set up a logger to log to the standard output and a log file using a configuration file as suggested in the question [Using Python logging in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-python-logging-in-multiple-modules). When I put the main routine (`main.py`) into a package (`mypackage`), everything works as intended. However, if I start the main routine in the project's root folder, the code breaks (`ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'`).

Is there a suggested solution for this problem?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
.
├── logging.conf
├── main.py
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mymodule.py
└── smodels.log
```

`logging.conf`:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,fileFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('smodels.log',)

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)-8s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-8s %(name)s:%(lineno)-3s %(message)s
datefmt=%H:%M:%S

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)-16s %(levelname)-8s %(filename)-s:%(lineno)-3s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
```

`main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mypackage import mymodule
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    logger.debug('This is a debug message.')
    logger.info('This is an info message.')
    mymodule.test()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

`__init__.py`:

```
import mymodule
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.conf',disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

`mymodule.py`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test():
    logger.debug('Module debug.')
    logger.info('Module info.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that `logging.conf` is not able to read:

**Please update your _*init*_.py as below:**

```
 import os
 import logging.config
 # logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
 basepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
 logging.config.fileConfig('%s/logging.conf' % basepath)
 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And please let me know if that fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works and I can now see my mistake. However, the `disable_existing_loggers=False` option is still needed for `logging.config.fileConfig()` when using multiple packages, each package containing this `__init__.py`.

Comment: ah please used that, forgot to add it back.