# Python logging module imported in different scripts

Tags: python, logging

In the python logging tutorial, there is an example with two python scripts : `myapp.py`, and `mylib.py`

The code is :

```
# myapp.py
import logging
import mylib

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Started')
    mylib.do_something()
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and

```
# mylib.py
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info('Doing something')
```

What I don't get is how the fact that using `basicConfig` in `myapp.py` changes the logging behavior in `mylib.py`.

I thought that in Python, when you import the same module in two different scripts, they are completely disconnected because the first one becomes `myapp.logging` and the second one `mylib.logging`.

EDIT :

I changed mylib.py code to

```
# mylib.py
import logging


def do_something():
    logging.warning('Doing something')


do_something()
```

When I run myapp.py, the logs are now printed in the console and do not appear in the log file anymore. How is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but you then import one module from the other and use its functions.

Comment: How do you explain that when I add "do_something()" at the end of mylib.py, the logs appear on the console and not in the log file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a bug (if I can call it that) in your understanding of python's modules:

> I thought that in Python, when you import the same module in two different scripts, they are completely disconnected because the first one becomes `myapp.logging` and the second one `mylib.logging`.

This is not the case.

The `import` statement is interpreted when it is encountered, and when you run python on your main program (`python myapp.py` or equivalent), that executes these lines:

```
import logging
```

(which imports the `logging` module),

```
import mylib
```

(which imports your library `mylib.py`),

```
def main():
```

(which binds the name `main` to the compiled bytecode of the function), and:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(which runs your `main` since the local name `__name__` is in fact bound to a string that compares equal to the string `__main__`).

So far, this is probably not very surprising (except perhaps that `def main()` is run at the point it's encountered in the import of `myapp.py`).

The part that probably *is* surprising is what happens during the execution of the two `import` statements.

The import machinery has evolved a bit (and is somewhat different in Python3 than Python2) but in essence it does these various things:

- locate the file (using `sys.path`)
- *if this is the first import of that file*, run all the executable statements in the file
- use or modify `sys.modules` (see below)
- bind the resulting object(s) (something of `<type 'module'>`, or a name within that) to the name(s) you supply (implicitly with regular `import`, explicitly with `from ... import ... as name`).

One of the key items here is the italicized part above.  The module is actually run on the first `import`.  The result of a successful import is a module instance, which is added to the `sys.modules` dictionary:

```
$ python2
...
>>> import sys
>>> x = sys.modules['copy_reg']
>>> print x
<module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'>
```

If, at this point, you ask python to *re-import* the module, it will quietly do almost nothing:

```
>>> import copy_reg
>>>
```

What happens here is that Python notices that the module is already loaded and in `sys.modules` so it simply extracts the already-loaded module entity (the one we also bound to symbol `x` above).  Then it binds the name `copy_reg` to this already-existing module.  If you `import copy_reg as y`:

```
>>> import copy_reg as y
```

the name is additionally bound to the symbol `y`:

```
>>> print x, y, copy_reg
<module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'> <module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'> <module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'>
```

To see that these are in fact the *same* module, we can use the `id` function, which prints the internal address of the underlying object:

```
>>> print id(x), id(y), id(copy_reg)
34367067648 34367067648 34367067648
```

(a different run of Python, or a different version, might produce a different set-of-3 address values here, but all three will match, because these all refer to the same module).

---

In any case, in your `main` in `myapp`, the symbol `logging` refers to the same `logging` module as the symbol `logging` in `mylib`.

In your original code, you call (from `do_something` in `mylib`) `logging.warning` to print a message *after* your `main` in `myapp` has already called the logging configuration code.  The log message therefore goes as directed.

In your edit, you've changed `mylib` to unconditionally call (via `do_something`) the `logging.warning` function as soon as the `import mylib` statement loads `myilb` to create the module.  That happens early on in `myapp`, *before* binding `main` to the code and *before* calling `main`.  So *that* message comes out on the console.

It's up to the logging code to decide whether to obey the (later) `basicConfig` call, made from your `main`.  As you can see from your own example, it does not honor an attempt to redirect the root configuration after printing a message (this is because it's set up its internal log handlers by then, as I recall).

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what i was looking for. Indeed, I didn't know that myapp.logging and myapp.mylib.logging have different names but point to the same Module object (beacuse Python checks if the module has already been loaded). Perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe log levels work globally in Python if you set them with `logging.basicConfig`.

The simplest answer is probably ([as jake77 suggested already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142723/1728179)):

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then set the level on that logger specifically:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # or whichever
```

There's a good article on best practices with logging [here](http://pieces.openpolitics.com/2012/04/python-logging-best-practices/). It may or may not be relevant to your case, but the best piece of advice it gives is that

> [...] libraries have no business configuring logging levels, formatters, or handlers.

There's also a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735146/1728179).

Comment: I'm trying to understand why when you make a file log_config.py where you write how your logging should work and import log_config in other scripts, these scripts behave the same as log_config. I know i can create a logger for each script but that's not my point.

Comment: Well the best practice is probably to just use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in each library script, and then do all of the configuration in your main entry-point script.

Comment: ...that is unless you want to configure multiple loggers logging to different files/consoles, which would be more complicated.

Comment: In that case you could configure your loggers in log_config, with different names, e.g.: `foo_log = logging.getLogger('foo')`, `bar_log = logging.getLogger('bar')`.

Then in each library script you fetch the appropriate logger with, e.g. `logging.getLogger('foo')`.

Comment: I agree that what you say works. My question is why does that work? I don't understand why using logging in the main entry-point script reflects on the other scripts. For me, once you import logging in a script, the functions that are imported become unique to this script.

Comment: Because of inheritance. Unless defined otherwise (instance level), you get the properties from the class in the main entry point.

Comment: what class? what inheritance? There is no inheritance involved here. It's not like I'm creating a child class of something. I think it has more to do with python scopes and namespaces

Comment: sorry, I doing something entirely different in parallel. What I mean is: you import a module. Then you use the module without creating a logger instance. Go on with @LeoHuckvale's answer, that will bring you there.

Answer (score -1):

According to [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects) logging module provides a interface for creating and storing loggers for future uses,

> multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

Also, using directly `logging.info` is equals to getting default named logger and using it. you can check source codes for more details about implementation of this mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create a logger instance in your module

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and then use

```
logger.info('message')
```

to log stuff.

Edit, based on comments on other answers.
Setting the level is not a necessity, unless you want to filter some messages, say log only abowe WARNING.
You definitely want to start a new console after changing your code.