# Using python 'logging' when logging.root has been redefined (Kivy)

Tags: python, logging, kivy

I've already seen [Using Python logging in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-python-logging-in-multiple-modules) and similar which recommend using:-

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in every module. However I'm also using Kivy as a front-end, which has its own logging code. To summarise, Kivy's logging code sets logging.root to its own class.

What this means for me is that the handlers which Kivy assigns aren't inherited by my child modules.

How do I get around this? I've even tried manually assigning handlers as below:-

```
logging.getLogger(my.module.name).addHandler(handler)
```

and it still doesn't seem to show up in my console log. Obviously I'd prefer not to do the above once per module, as well.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'd like to set up the Kivy app to be able to handle modules which use the 'recommended'
log method, without any change to the module code.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [`logging.Logger.getChild`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getChild)? In particular, in your module, call

```
mylogger = logging.getLogger().getChild(__name__)
```

If the module is imported after `kivy.logger` has been imported, the root logger's name will be `kivy`, and thus `mylogger`'s name will be `kivy.module.name`, and more importantly, it will propagate its messages to the root logger, `kivy`. On the other hand, if `kivy.logger` has not been imported, `mylogger`'s name will just be `module.name`, and thus come with no handlers attached by default.

Example:
`test.py`:

```
import logging

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger().getChild(__name__)
        self.value = 0

    def act(self):
        self.value += .5
        self.logger.warning("MyClass.act: value: {}".format(self.value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc = MyClass()
    mc.act()
    mc.act()
    mc.act()
```

And `app.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from test import MyClass

class AnApp(App):
    mc = ObjectProperty()
    value = NumericProperty(0)
    def action_c(self, dt=0):
        self.value += 1
        self.mc.act()
        Logger.info("action_c: value now {}".format(self.value))
        
    def build(self):
        self.mc = MyClass()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.action_c, 1)
        return Widget()
AnApp().run()
```

And `app_wo_kivy.py`:

```
import logging
from test import MyClass
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

mc = MyClass()
mc.act()
mc.act()
```

#### Edit

Another approach: In the kivy app, put this first:

```
from kivy.logger import Logger
import logging
logging.Logger.manager.root = Logger # before importing modules using logging
```

With this, you should be able to just use the standard way of getting a logger (`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`). This will work for existing modules (assuming they do not mess with `logging` themselves ...). `logging.Logger.manager` holds the logger dictionary and determines the hierarchy. Whenever a new logger is created with `logging.getLogger`, [`logging.Manager._fixupParents`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1071) gets called, which, when no other parent logger can be found, assigns `logging.Logger.manager.root`  as parent. Without the above line, this is still the original root logger, hence that will be used.

Now I have no idea whether this might have unintended consequences; but at least logger name parsing should not be compromised, as the root logger's name never gets checked.

Comment: That's a neat workaround, but not exactly on point, because while this would work with and without Kivy, it requires the module code to use 'getChild', which deviates from the 'usual' method I mention in my question. In particular this means I'd have to modify any external libraries/modules used if I wanted to get their logs, or conversely that anyone using my library/module would see something unfamiliar (even if it works the same!).

Comment: @NgOon-Ee the question did not mention modules other than yours (and a comment sure could explain the different approach). But see my edit, which should fill all your requirements (i.e. only modification needed is in kivy app)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question appropriately. Will test this out, if it works as you say then the answer is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: There is one other instance of the `root` logger that `kivy` does *not* reassign: `logging.Logger.root`. This is only used [in `logging.Logger.getChild`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1383), to determine the name of the new logger. If it were set to the kivy logger, all loggers created with `getChild` would have a name starting with `kivy.`, but loggers created just with `getLogger` would not. So leaving it as default is probably a good thing.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment.  The key to making the "other approach" work, is to set `logging.Logger.manager.root` _before_ importing any modules using normal python logging.  Then logging works!  I'll edit the answer to that effect.