# Python logging multiple modules logger not working outside main program

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

My goal is to log from multiple modules, while only configuring the logger in one place - in the main program. As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-python-logging-in-multiple-modules), one should include

```
logging.config.fileConfig('/path/to/logging.conf')
```

in the main program, then in all other modules include

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I believe that's what I've done below, yet I get unexpected behaviour.

### c.py

```
# c.py
import logging
import logging.config
import d

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.warning('logging from c')
d.foo()
```

### d.py

```
# d.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# this will print when d is imported
logger.warning('logging from d on import')

def foo():
    # this does not print
    logger.warning("logging from d on call foo()")
```

### Output

```
$ python c.py
logging from d on import
logging from c
```

What I would expect, is that when `d.foo()` executes in `c.py`, that a message would be logged from `d`, however, that's not the case. This is confusing because when the logger is called from module level in `d`, it logs a message to the console, but when called from inside `foo()` it doesn't.

### Config file

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(message)s
datefmt=
```

### Further analysis

So I've noticed that if I remove the line

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
```

from `c.py`, then logging from `d.foo()` works as expected. So there's either something wrong in the configuration file or due to the fact that I *provide* a configuration file something causes the logger in `d.py` to get messed up.

### Question

1. Why does a message get logged from `d` when called from module level, but not from inside `d.foo()`?
2. And how can I achieve the goal of logging from multiple modules, while only configuring the logging in the main program?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that

```
import d
```

comes before

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
```

as pointed out by @davidejones. Here's **why:**

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html), when `logging.config.fileConfig()` is called, its default behaviour is to *disable* any existing loggers. So when `import d` happens, `logger` is initialised in `d`, then when `logging.config.fileConfig()` is called, the `logger` in `d` is disabled, which is why we didn't see any logging when `d.foo()` was called.

### Solution

`logging.config.fileConfig()` takes an argument, `disable_existing_loggers`, which is `True` by default. Use

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf", disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

And output becomes

```
>>> python c.py
logging from d on import
logging from c
logging from d on call foo()
```

As expected.

Comment: ah nice i forgot about the disable loggers setting, glad you found what you needed this seems like a much better solution

Comment: Thanks. You definitely helped me get on the right track. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the import of d is happening before the config of the logger so doing something like this might give what you want?

```
# c.py
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

import d


logger.warning('logging from c')
d.foo()
```

it gives me these results

```
logging from d on import
logging from c
logging from d on call foo()
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the code it might make more sense to have a seperate file to have the logging setup then you import that once in you main file the other modules will have it then and it doesn't look as messy. So maybe having a `logsetup.py` like this

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
```

and then c.py looking like this instead which still gives the same results

```
# c.py
import logsetup
import logging
import d

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.warning('logging from c')
d.foo()
```

Comment: I see. I guess when I `import d` before configuring the logger, the logger in d is left without a handler, so it doesn't print anywhere. But when I don't include the statement `logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")` at all I would expect neither logger to print anything (which is not the case and they both do print to console). But I guess in that case both loggers end up with a default console handler...

Comment: Yea i think that's a fair assessment. I've updated my answer to do it slightly differently. I think maybe having a separate file to setup the logger would be best. Similar to how a framework like django or flask might have a settings.py file to deal with this kind of thing, hope it helps

Comment: I like your second approach. I'll accept that answer after some time if I don't get another perspective from someone else. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hey @FilipKilibarda did you find any other solutions in the end?

Comment: Hey @davidejones, I've answered my own question with the solution I thought was most straightforward.