# Handling logs and writing to a file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a module name acms and inside that have number of python files.The main.py has  calls to other python files.I have added logs in those files, which are displayed on console but i also want to write these logs in a file called all.log, i tried with setting log levels and logger in a file called log.py but didnt get the expected format,since am new to python am getting difficulty in handling logs

Comment: I hope this will help you
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735146/8339179)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `logging` module and use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Then it will use the correct logger with the options that you have set up.

See the [thinkpad-scripts](https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts/tree/master/tps) project for its logging. Also the [logging cookbook](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations.) has a section for logging to multiple locations.

We use the following to log to the console and the syslog:

```
    kwargs = {}
    dev_log = '/dev/log'
    if os.path.exists(dev_log):
        kwargs['address'] = dev_log
    syslog = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(**kwargs)
    syslog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(syslog_format)
    syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(syslog)
```