# Logging from multiple modules to the same log file

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple project structure - my main module calls two other modules residing within the same directory. I followed the instructions [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735146/722950) to set up my test.

My code is as follows:

Main module:

```
# log_test.py
import logging
import imported_1
import imported_2

def main():

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.debug("This is a debug message")
    logger.info("For your info")
    logger.warning("This is a warning message")
    logger.error("This is an error message")
    logger.critical("This is a critical message")

    imported_1.one_fn(5, 6)
    imported_2.two_fn(10, 20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The imported modules - imported_1.py

```
# imported_1.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def one_fn(x, y):
    print(f"Logging function one with {x} and {y}")
    logger.info(f"Logging function one with {x} and {y}")
```

And imported_2.py

```
# imported_2.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def two_fn(x, y):
    print(f"Logging function two with {x} and {y}")
    logger.info(f"Logging function one with {x} and {y}")
```

The generated log file `test.log` only contains entries from the main `log_test.py` module. The imported modules are not logged here:

```
2019-12-21 18:26:41,351 - __main__ - DEBUG - This is a debug message
2019-12-21 18:26:41,351 - __main__ - INFO - For your info
2019-12-21 18:26:41,351 - __main__ - WARNING - This is a warning message
2019-12-21 18:26:41,351 - __main__ - ERROR - This is an error message
```

I am looking for log messages from the imported modules to show up in the same log file as specified by basicConfig. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the loggers of imported1 and import2 to know the original logger you created, they need to be its children.
In python loggers are arranged by '.', so logger `a.b.c` is a child of logger `a.b` which is a child of `a`

You can achieve what you want this way:
In `log_test.py`

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
```

In `imported_1.py`

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger.' + __name__) # will be my_logger.imported_1
```

In `imported_2.py`

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger.' + __name__) # will be my_logger.imported_2
```

You can check out more here
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for.