# How to define logging in one place in Python?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, python-logging

I am new Python and I want to define the following logging code in python in one place so that it can be used in other python files(class or non-class). In case of Java, we use log4j or slf4j as part of jar files and we simply define as `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("class name")`, I want achieve exactly like this so that I can use loger in any python module/s. Currently I define the config in all the classes.

```java
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("debug.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
```

I have also gone through this SO link [Using logging in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules)

Also please suggest the most recommended approach for medium to large project having more number of python files.

Comment: What is wrong with the answers to the question you mentioned ?

Comment: Sir, I want in common place so that I can use simply `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and I can use `logger.debug("something")`. Currently I define in all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this link https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/, the author has mentioned a better practice. There may be better recommended approach.
You have to do in the following manner.

1. Define `logging.json` file as mentioned in the link.
2. Define a python file called `LogSetup.py` and add below the code.

> ```
> def setup_logging(default_path='logging.json', default_level=logging.DEBUG, env_key='LOG_CFG'):
>     """Setup logging configuration"""
>     path = default_path
>     value = os.getenv(env_key, None)
>     if value:
>         path = value
>     if os.path.exists(path):
>         with open(path, 'rt') as f:
>             config = json.load(f)
>         logging.config.dictConfig(config)
>     else:
>         logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
> ```

3. Call the above file like this `LogSetup.setup_logging()` in the main method.
   I provide below the code snippet.

logger = logging.getLogger(**name**)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LogSetup.setup_logging()
    logger.debug("This is a debug message ...")
```

It looks good for me, others may recommend the better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

One option to make your logging handler available everywhere, is to make it a [built-in identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

a.py:

```
import logging
import builtins
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s %(filename)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("/tmp/debug.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)

builtins.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("module a!")
import b
```

b.py:

```
logger.info(msg='This is from module b.py')

def foo():
    logger.info('Log message from b.foo()')

foo()
```

Output:

```
2020-02-14 20:18:17,549 a.py [INFO] module a!
2020-02-14 20:18:17,550 b.py [INFO] This is from module b.py
2020-02-14 20:18:17,550 b.py [INFO] Log message from b.foo()
```