# How to save the logs from a external package in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I'm working on a python project which needs to use a third-party module such as tweepy https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy. I would like to save the logs output from this third-party module to a local file so I can check it regularly. It happens that [root logger](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/5630d6b56b38c43d8e7f9ec93819066569042a65/tweepy/streaming.py#L23) is used inside tweepy so the logs are output to console. In this case, no filehandler is yet added to the root logger, so how could I save the logs to a local file?

One way I think of is to use  `python run.py > ~/project/logs/test.log` to redirect all logs to the local file `test.log`, but is this the best way to do it?  I can already see a downside: it will save all logs not only the ones from the third-party module.

Comment: You can add your own log handler to Tweepy's logger. :)

Comment: oh right, so Logger is actually a singleton pattern, so I only need to add a Filehandler once, and all the logs will be output to the same place. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: No, import this one logger and add a desired handler to it. You can have other loggers with other (or same) handlers.

Comment: I found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules