# Can't get my head around logging in multiple modules

Tags: python, logging

I've been going around in circles with this for the last four hours. I've read the docs and [this other SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules). [This GitHub code](https://gist.github.com/delicb/4540990) recommends importing modules *after* logging has been setup in the main script, whereas [this post](https://www.pylenin.com/blogs/python-logging-guide/#logging-from-multiple-modules) suggests each module should have a complete implementation of the logger.

The way logging works has me completely mystified. I'm running Python 3.9.

Here the code at the top of my main script:

```
import logging


def logger():
    # Adding the following line logs each message twice to the console
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    # Create the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create handlers
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    fh = logging.FileHandler('log.log', mode='w')
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create formatters
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[ %(levelname)s ] %(name)s : %(message)s'))
    fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [ %(levelname)s ] %(name)s : %(message)s'))

    # Add handlers to logger
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger


logger = logger()

import log_module  # Linter complains but at this point I don't care anymore

logger.debug('Help')

log_module.foo()
```

In `log_module.py`, I have the following:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def foo():
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.debug('Debugging in module')
```

If I run the main script, I only get one log message: `[ DEBUG ] __main__ : Help`.

If I uncomment the line with `basicConfig` in the `logger` function, I get **three** log messages, unformatted:

```
[ DEBUG ] __main__ : Help
DEBUG:__main__:Help
DEBUG:log_module:Debugging in module
```

If I copy the whole `logger()` function over to `log_module.py`, I get the output I'm expecting, in the correct format, which is:

```
[ DEBUG ] __main__ : Help
[ DEBUG ] log_module : Debugging in module
```

However, it seems very silly to copy entire chunks of code across modules.

- What am I doing wrong?
- What should I be doing instead?
- Does this need to be this convoluted just to get logs from multiple modules?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - What am I doing wrong?

You're configuring one logger and using a different logger. When you call `logger()` in the main script, the returned logger is the `__main__` because that is what `__name__` evaluates to from the main script. When you call `logging.getLogger()` from `log_module.py`, you get a module named `log_module`.

> - What should I be doing instead?

Either explicitly configure the `log_module` logger by calling a `configure_logger` function that accepts a logger instance as an argument, or configure the root logger (get the root logger by calling `logging.getLogger()` with no arguments). The root logger's configuration will be inherited by the others.

> - Does this need to be this convoluted just to get logs from multiple modules?

Once you understand that loggers are a hierarchy, it's a little simpler conceptually. It works nicely when you have nested packages/modules.

- `logging.getLogger()` (root logger)

  - `logging.getLogger('foo')` (inherits configuration from root logger)

    - `logging.getLogger('foo.bar')` (inherits configuration from `foo`)
    - `logging.getLogger('foo.baz')` (inherits configuration from `foo`)

Comment: Typo, I think: `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` *both* inherit configuration from `foo`.

Comment: Thank you. It took a while for me to realise that, to make it short, the logger instance in the main script should simply not have a name... It works when I'm using the above barebones scripts, so thanks a lot for clearing that out. However, as soon as I import a module such as PySide into those scripts, every log message is doubled with a non-formatted one. I have not changed anything else otherwise, and still don't understand what logger instance is producing that (since I'm only calling *my* loggers).

Comment: I managed to make this work when PySide is imported by adding the following line immediately after I instantiate my logger in the main script, before I do anything else: `for h in logger.handlers: logger.removeHandler(h)`. This removes all the handlers which might be there (PySide adds only one). I don't know if this is the way this should be done, but if so maybe it should be added to the answer.

Comment: It sounds like you're calling `logging.basicConfig()`, which adds a stream handler to the root logger, and also adding handlers your module loggers. If you add a handler to the root logger and to a module logger, that would cause multiple log messages. When writing an **application**, in most cases, you only want to configure the root logger. Sometimes you'll want to configure a separate file handler each module of your application so each module logs to a separate path. A well-behaved **library** will not configure the root logger (i.e. importing a file should never modify the root logger).

Comment: @Cirrocumulus If you reply with a link to current code, I can take a look at your specific situation later tonight.

Comment: @jisrael18 Like I wrote I've been on this for the most part of the day, so I'm absolutely positive I have no call to `basicConfig()` anywhere (this has been part of the problem). I've just double-checked with a project-wide search. Maybe it's a PySide6/Qt issue or bug? My code works as expected with my `removeHandler`hack, but if you want to have a look the project is here: https://github.com/Merkwurdichliebe/beacon2map — Thanks a lot.