# Python - Logging in multiple modules and child loggers (Azure Monitor)

Tags: python, logging, azure-application-insights

I have read many docs online (Logging Cookbook, Python reference, many SO posts) but I struggle to make this working.

Context:

- FastAPI application
- Docker container for deployment
- Azure Monitor/Application Insights as logging destination

My needs:

- (logging) Define handlers, formatters and filters only in one place
- (logging) Send "info" and below to handler A, above "info" to handler B
- (project) Structure my project correctly so the above will work

Here is my current project structure (some files omitted for brevity):

```
dockerfile
main.py
requirements.txt
--logger
----logger.py
--some other module
----module.py
```

Here is my logger.py file:

```
import logging
from logging import LogRecord
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureEventHandler

def log_warning_or_below(record : LogRecord):
    if(record.levelname in [logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARN, logging.WARNING]):
            return True
    return False

def build_custom_events_handler():
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    handler=AzureEventHandler(connection_string=connection_string)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.addFilter(log_warning_or_below)

    return handler

def init():
    custom_events_handler = build_custom_events_handler()
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO,
        datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',
        handlers=[custom_events_handler]
    )
    logging.Formatter.converter = timetz

init()
```

And here is my main.py file:

```
....various imports...
import logger.logger

logger = logger.logger.getLogger('main')
logger.info('Start of main')

def _create_app() -> FastAPI:
    api = FastAPI(
        title='my title',
        description="some desc",
        version='1.0',
    )
    return api

app = _create_app()

@app.post('/myroute')
def do_something():
    logger.info('inside the function')
    return 'my route was hit'
```

From my comprehension of the hierarchy, the root logger (not named), in my logger.py file, will be configured with the handler and various options. Any child logger to which I send log events (e.g., the logger named "main") will also send records to the root logger, exact?

Currently, this setup doesn't work. I have deployed my app to a Docker container and I run it locally. The FastAPI default logs appear in Azure (the handler) but no other log I send to the logger do.

What am I doing wrong?

Regarding my project structure, I read it is good practice to name your logger such as `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` but I am guessing my structure prevents this from working in the `main.py` file, as it is located one level higher than the `logger.py` file?

- Create a "static" logger, with static methods, in `logger.py`, to log events (it works, but I prefer having a logger per module)
- Using a Jupyter notebook, with the `logger.py` file above and the following code (it works for this test only):

```
import os
import sys
p = os.path.abspath('..')
sys.path.insert(1, p)
from logger.logger import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('bob')

logger.info('test')
```

- Wrapping my head around a `DictConfig` but it doesn't seem as easy as I think
- Reading [Using logging in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules) but many possible solutions and they do not seem to all apply here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code to Logging in multiple modules with flask
File structure

```
project/
|-- dockerfile
|-- main.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- logger/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- logger.py
|-- some_other_module/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module.py
```

```py
import logging
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

def configure_logging():
    connection_string = '  '  
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string=connection_string)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

```py
from logger.logger import configure_logging


configure_logging()


fastapi_app = FastAPI()

@fastapi_app.get("/")
def read_root():
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
  
    logger.info("This is an INFO log message")
    logger.warning("This is a WARNING log message")
    
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}


@fastapi_app.get("/home")
def home():
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    logger.info("Accessed the /home route")
    
    return {"message": "Welcome to the /home route!"}


flask_app = Flask(__name__)

@flask_app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'


def run_fastapi():
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(fastapi_app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

def run_flask():
    import os
    os.system("gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app.main:flask_app")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fastapi_thread = Thread(target=run_fastapi)
    flask_thread = Thread(target=run_flask)

    fastapi_thread.start()
    flask_thread.start()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sampath. I followed part of your code and it works now! :)