# Add custom log records in Django

Tags: django, logging, django-settings, django-logging

I've added the following logging configuration to my Django App's `settings.py` file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

Now, I simply want to add some custom log records to one of my views in `views.py`, but it appears the logger is `NOTSET`, which means only levels of `warning` and higher are logged:

```
import logging
from django.http import JsonResponse

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def testing(request):
    logger.info("Doesn't show...")
    logger.warning(f"Log Level: {logger.level} = {logging.getLevelName(logger.level)}")
    return JsonResponse({"Hello": "World"})
```

The snippet above logs the following:

```
Log Level: 0 = NOTSET
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the logger's level not set (even though I clearly set it in `settings.py`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why this behavior?

The **`logging.getLogger(__name__)`** statement will initialize a python logger with ***a dotted path to the current module***. In your case, it would be **`my_app.views`**. Django is not able to understand the logs that you have created from the **`views.py`** since your logger name **`my_app.views`** which is not listed in **`settings.py`**. Django won't do anything to the logs if you are not specified the ***logger name/ logger-name pattern*** accordingly.

### How `warning` logs are displayed?

I hope this So post this explains well, [**Python logging not outputting anything**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016056/python-logging-not-outputting-anything)

## Solution

#### Option-1

change either your **logger name** in ***`settings.py`***

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'my_app.views': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

**Key Change:** I have changed the logger name **`django`** to **`my_app.views`**

#### Option-2

Specify ***logger name*** in the **`getLogger`** method

```
logger = logging.getLogger('django')
```

**Key Point:** The name of the logger and the logger defined in the Django Settings module should be same.

Comment: Why we should use: os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO') , instead just 'INFO' . I've print the value of DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL on the shell, but it returns None.

Answer (score 2):

Since you configured the logger for `'django'` and your module is (presumably) not in the `django` package, you need to get the `'django'` logger explicitly:

```py
# logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger('django')
```

Otherwise, you get a logger that is not configured so `logger.level` is `NOTSET`.

Django, however, will use your logging configuration.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html:

> The logger name hierarchy is analogous to the Python package hierarchy, and identical to it if you organise your loggers on a per-module basis using the recommended construction `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. That’s because in a module, `__name__` is the module’s name in the Python package namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Because `logging.getLogger(__name__)` create a python logger with a path to the current module and since you don't register this logger in your setting, Django is not able to understand the logger that you have created from the `views.py`. One solution is to register it in your setting as @JPG said before. Another solution is to create it manually. For example you can create an `Utils.py` file and create this function to create your logger.

```
import logging
def get_view_logger(view_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(view_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log/' + view_name + '.log'),
                                       when='midnight', backupCount=20, encoding="utf8")
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] : %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

You can customize each of component of your logger like handler, formatter and etc.

Comment: `Django is not able to understand the logs` → Django doesn't play any part in "understanding" the logs. Python's `logging` library simply returns a logger that is not configured.

Comment: Django doesn't play any part in understanding the *logger* either. It might even be accurate to say that Django plays no part at all in this case.