# Python log level cannot be set

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Here is my code

```
logger = logging.getLogger("JarvisAI")
# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler(logname)
c_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logging
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
```

Running `logger.info("Test")` does not produce anything in the logfile.
However `logger.warning` and other higher log level works fine both in console and file.
Pls help.

Comment: Relatead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016056/python-logging-not-outputting-anything . I'm not flagging this as a duplicate, because that code and answer are not directly helpful to this question, even though the issue is the same. But a simple search for [python logging no output](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+logging+no+output) here on StackOverflow would have been a good thing to do for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger itself also has a logging level, and that needs to be below (or above, depending on your point of view) that of the handlers to show the handlers' output:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

(or even debug level: the formatters' levels will prevent debugging info from being output anyway) will do that.

This is also shown in the first code block of [the Python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook). Have a read through it.

The reason you are getting warning and higher log level output, is because warning is the default logging level.