# Python neither logging to console nor to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I have following code in [my colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VA8EStfjt9KnK46WumF5AhURbcW7pPGl?usp=sharing):

```
# Cell 1
import logging


# Cell 2
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.configureLogger()
    self.fileLogger.info('info log to file')
    self.consoleLogger.debug('debug log to console')    

  def configureLogger(self):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144390/6357916
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)
    self.fileLogger = logging.getLogger('fileLogger2')
    if not self.fileLogger.hasHandlers():
        self.fileLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter1 = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s,%(message)s")
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter1)
        self.fileLogger.addHandler(file_handler)

    self.consoleLogger = logging.getLogger('consoleLogger2')
    if not self.consoleLogger.hasHandlers():
        self.consoleLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter2 = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter2)
        self.consoleLogger.addHandler(console_handler)

c = MyClass()
```

There `MyClass` has a method called `configureLogger()` which configures two loggers:

1. `fileLogger`: logs to file
2. `consoleLogger`: logs t console

`MyClass.__init__()` call this method and uses both of these loggers to log single message each. But nothing gets logged to console. Nor does `log.txt` file gets created.

I am expecting it to log `debug log to console` to console and `info log to file` to file. This is how it is behaving on my local machine, but fails on colab

What I am missing here?

**Update**

After commenting both line containing `if ...`, it is now printing

```
2023-04-07 20:10:20,860,info log to file
```

to file and

```
INFO:fileLogger2:info log to file
debug log to console
DEBUG:consoleLogger2:debug log to console
```

to console.

It means those `if` conditions are `false` causing no file handler are getting added and that is why nothing was getting logged. But those if conditions should be `true` initially right (as logger should not have any handler to start with)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger names `fileLogger2` and `consoleLogger2` are both children of the root logger, which has the default level set to `WARNING`. This means that the messages with lower log levels (like `INFO` and `DEBUG`) will not propagate to the root logger and won't be logged. You can set the `propagate` attribute of your loggers to `False`, which would prevent the messages from being passed to the parent loggers allowing you to see the log messages as expected:

```py
def configureLogger(self):
    self.fileLogger = logging.getLogger('fileLogger2')
    if not self.fileLogger.hasHandlers():
        self.fileLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.fileLogger.propagate = False  # Add this line
        formatter1 = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s,%(message)s")
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter1)
        self.fileLogger.addHandler(file_handler)

    self.consoleLogger = logging.getLogger('consoleLogger2')
    if not self.consoleLogger.hasHandlers():
        self.consoleLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.consoleLogger.propagate = False  # Add this line
        formatter2 = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter2)
        self.consoleLogger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate

---

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can remove existing handlers by adding `logging.root.handlers.clear()` to your `configureLogger()` method. Also, because we remove any existing handlers we do not need to care any propagation (as there is nothing to propagate to), so remove `self.consoleLogger.propagate = False` line I suggested previously:

```py
def configureLogger(self):
    logging.root.handlers.clear()  # Add this line

    ...
    self.consoleLogger.propagate = False  # Remove this (x2)
    ...
```

Comment: Tried, it does not work. [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FiFLyd8_GEDRscmryco37zEX_tBcQf2n?usp=sharing) is the updated notebook. Also setting root loggers level to `DEBUG` doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Can you please try adding `logging.root.handlers.clear()` at the beginning of `configureLogger()`?

Comment: Utter thank you!!! It worked perfectly. Also `propgate=False` was not required. Updated the notebook linked in the comment. I got the reason: `hasHandlers()` checks if there is any handler on parent logger too. So, no handler was getting added to any of `consoleLogger` and `fileLogger`. Now am not guessing why original code work on my local machine but not on colab!!! Any guesses? Did it work on your local machine?

Comment: yes, your code did nothing due to `if` condition being `False` because of existing handlers. Once we removed them, your code kicked in. I edited the answer to reflect that. If that solved your problem, please mark answer accepted.

Comment: Also a note to colab users. If you are writing logs to google drive, it may take several minutes for a log file to actually get updated. In my case, it did get reflected after at least 5 minutes. Till that time I was brain storming and constantly changing code to fix why log file might not be getting created. And suddenly after 5 minutes, log file got created with all logs for several different runs corresponding to my code changes!